# Ember.js onewayBinding is not working for objects

Tags: ember.js

Does anyone tried oneway binding in ember.js? It is not working for me.

Here is my snippet.

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    user : { "name" : "Albert"} ,
    userCopyBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay("this.user"); 
});
```

In handlebars:

```
 <label>user name </label>
 {{view Ember.TextField  valueBinding="userCopy.name"}}

 <label>fist name is {{user.name}}</label>
```

If I Enter text in the input it changes the 'user's name' also. Am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have a typo, it should be, `Ember.Binding.oneWay`.

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar, Thanks, Now I corrected my typo. I think the oneway binding is not working for objects. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your comments you stated:

> I think the oneway binding is not working for objects. Right?

Yes right. As stated in the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/bindings/):

> A binding creates a link between two properties such that when one changes, the other one is updated to the new value automatically. Bindings can connect properties on the same object, or across two different objects.

So, yes `oneWay` binding only works for properties and not objects.

Change your code to this to make it work:

```
App.UserController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  user: Ember.Object.create({name: "Albert"}),
  userNameBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay("this.user.name"); 
});
```

In the template then:

```
<label>user name </label>
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="userName"}}
<label>fist name is {{userName}}</label>
```

[Demo here](http://jsbin.com/anopal/2/edit).

Hope it helps.